# Standard Unix/Linux utility for testing every input line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

I am writing a Bash script which should test if every line in input meet certain condition.

Is there a way to take the predicate and reduce all the line to either 0 or 1 so I don't have to code the looping code myself using a utility that is routinely standard or readily available in Linux distributions?

Comment: Please can you provide more information? e.g: example input and expected output data.

Answer (score -1):

Sample data (we want all lines that contain "*want*"):

```bsh
$ cat x
not this
want this
not that
want that
```

---

You coud use [`awk`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk):

- Print a `1` if the line matches regex `/want/`
- Print a `0` if the line does not match

```bsh
$ cat x | awk '{if(match($0,/want/)){print 1}else{print 0}}'
0
1
0
1
```

---

Or try [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

- Replace lines that contain just `1` with `0` (otherwise they will pass through as a `1`)
- Replace lines containing "*want*" with a `1`
- Replace lines that are not a `1` with a `0`

```bsh
$ cat x | sed -re 's/^1$/0/' -e 's/^.*want.*$/1/' -e 's/^[^1][^$].*$/0/'
0
1
0
1
```

Comment: I'm going to ask for more information from OP... If you're not happy with a one liner, then I think the answer has to be "_no_" - it doesn't get much more simple that the `awk` example above...